# Delete all words from sentense that are shorter that 4 letters

Tags: clips, expert-system

I want to delete all words from sentense that are shorter that 4 letters. Print result sentence and count of deleted words. Print result on the screen and in the text file.

CLIPS Expert System. There are few guides all over the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start:

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate sentence
   (multislot text)
   (slot deleted_count (default 0)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule delete
   ?f <- (sentence (text $?b ?word&:(< (str-length ?word) 4) $?e)
                   (deleted_count ?count))
   =>
   (modify ?f (text ?b ?e) (deleted_count (+ 1 ?count))))
CLIPS> (assert (sentence (text the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (run)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-4     (sentence (text quick brown jumped over lazy dogs) (deleted_count 3))
For a total of 2 facts.
CLIPS>
```

When asking questions on Stack Overflow you should make at a least a token effort to demonstrate that you've read the available documentation and made an effort to solve the problem.

Comment: thx! i was trying to make something like this `(defmethod Ichi
 ()
 (bind ?input (explode$ "hammer dril saw screw"))
 (bind ?result "")

 (loop-for-count (?i 1 4) do

  (bind ?word (nth$ ?i ?input))

   (if (< (length$ ?word) 4) then
    (str-cat ?word ?result)
   )

  
     (printout t ?word crlf)

 )

 ?result

)`